# Get the Image positions from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting the **Image path** from Json file & assigning the image path to JS variable as below :

```
var maskedImageUrla = "";

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {
        for (let layer of json.layers) {
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0) {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) {
                    if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers) {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) maskedImageUrla = tl.src;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now i need to get the **left [x] & top [y]** positions of that image....

From below json file, How to get **x & y** values and display inside class **img.css**

**Json** :

```
{
  "path" : " shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : ""   
  },
  "name" : "shape",
  "layers" : [
    {     
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {         
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {         
          "x" : 50,
          "layers" : [
            {

              "src" : "http://sitename.com/images/oneheart.png",             
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {              
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],   
          "y" : 69,       
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],      
      "name" : "loveshape_17"
    }
  ]
}
```

**img.css**

```
var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla,
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": 50, // get x value from json
                    "top": 69   // get y value from json
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is  [Full json in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/eggmG1QP) &  [full  JS code](https://pastebin.com/ZgEe8wQ0)

Comment: **img.css** looks like JS. Is that OK?

Comment: @FZs thats right..... `img.css` is present inside js code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the x / y in a variable when parsing your JSON data.

```
var maskedImageUrla = "";
var coordinates = { x: 0, y: 0 };

$.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {
    for (let layer of json.layers) {
        if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0) {
            for (let temp of layer.layers) {
                if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                else if (temp.layers) {
                    for (let tl of temp.layers)
                        if (tl.src) {
                            maskedImageUrla = tl.src;
                            coordinates.x = tl.x;
                            coordinates.y = tl.y;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then retrieve the data and add the right units to the CSS.

```
img.css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "left": coordinates.x + "px",
    "top": coordinates.y + "px" 
});
```

I have edited the answer to maybe suit your needs better. You should still note that this might not be what you are looking for, because your file format has multiple X/Y values spread around here and there. The value with src has only x: 0 and y: 0, so you should maybe store the `temp.x` and `temp.y` instead.

I'm not familiar with your JSON file format, but I hope this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Sure , I will attach px , but can you please give me code for how to get json value in img.css  class

Comment: I updated my answer. I can't give you exact code, because I'm not totally sure what you are doing, but this example should help you.

Comment: Well, your solution is working fine when i replaced with `temp.x` & `temp.y`..... but why its adding `z-index :2` for the `div` at the end `<div class="masked-img" style="position: fixed; left: 50px; top: 69px; width: 513px; height: 475px; z-index: 2;">` ?  please check [code here](https://pastebin.com/hQYL7FqQ)  in the [link](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/test73.html)